# FindRoot of matrix operation equations

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

I have a question in `FindRoot` of matrix operation equations.

It's my first time use Matrix operation in `FindRoot`, i have write a simple example, it shows `FindSolve` can solve Matrix equations.

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}; b = {{1, 3}, {2, 2}};

{c} /. FindRoot[
  c == a.b - IdentityMatrix[2],
  {c, IdentityMatrix[2]}
  ]
```

Very fast and simple!

Can I write a new expression in `FindRoot` like

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}; b = {{1, 3}, {2, 2}};
d = {{1, 1}, {3, 3}};
{c} /. FindRoot[
  var == d.b,
  c == a.var - IdentityMatrix[2],
  {c, IdentityMatrix[2]}
  ]
```

and return `c` and `var`, well, `var` is some function result I want update in `FindRoot` and used to the equation I want to solve like `c == a.var`. `var` isn't need to solve.

Above code have issues. Here is my idea:

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}; b = {{1, 3}, {2, 2}};
d = {{1, 1}, {3, 3}};
{var = d.b, c /. FindRoot[
   c == a.var - IdentityMatrix[2],
   {c, IdentityMatrix[2]}
   ]}
```

Can I achieve same result in a more compact form？Putting expressions (eg. `var`) that don't need to solve into `FindRoot` will cause errors.

Comment: By the way, can I display the Math symbol more comfortable when I paste the code from notebook to this question? ` \[CapitalOmega]` is not easy to reading.

Comment: It might be helpful if you show the matrixequation you try to solve ! Your first example seems to be  unclear

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, Thank you, first example is to show `FindRoot` can solve Matrix equations, I revised the question and  show the matrix equation I try to solve.

Comment: `q` is not defined when the definition of `qE0` refers to its parts. For your simple example, `Solve` works: `c /. Solve[{c == a . b - IdentityMatrix[2], c \[Element] Matrices[{2, 2}]}, c][[1]]`

Comment: See [`Additional useful buttons for our M.SE editor`](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1043/9362)

Comment: @BobHanlon Thank you, M.SE editor is very helpful. I will check my code again.

Comment: @BobHanlon, Thank you, there is typo for `q`, i have revised `q` as `q0` when define `qE0`, output is `The function value {Null} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1}`

Comment: I have simplified my question, thanks for all helpful comments. have a good day!

Comment: Why not  `a.d.b - IdentityMatrix[2]` directively? There no equation in your examples indeed.

Comment: @cvgmt, Thanks for comment. Because I have many many constrains equations, and I want put the expression of some variable in `FindRoot` for the readability(I know I can define `functions`, i just want return the variables and the root same time, well, `Table` can do this, and from Bob, `With` is a good choice), and also use the result of `FindRoot` to return another expression, I want `FindRoot` can distinguish the equation which not need to be solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}; b = {{1, 3}, {2, 2}};
d = {{1, 1}, {3, 3}};

With[{var = d . b},
 c /. Solve[{c == a . var - IdentityMatrix[2],
     c ∈ Matrices[2]}, c][[1]]]

(* {{20, 35}, {45, 74}} *)

With[{var = d . b},
 c /. FindRoot[c == a . var - IdentityMatrix[2],
   {c, IdentityMatrix[2]}]]

(* {{20., 35.}, {45., 74.}} *)
```